# Button hides other elements behind it when clicked

Tags: android

I'm working on the UI of my project, specifically I'm in a compound view extending a FrameLayout. Inside it I have two buttons, one (the smaller one) on top of the other (the larger one). I managed to make the smaller button be always on top with the 'android:elevation' property. The problem is that when I run the app and I click on the larger button, it hides the smaller one behind it, despite having a lower elevation property. I want the smaller one to be always on top even if the user clicks on the other button, but I can't manage to make it work.

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="80dp"
  android:layout_height="80dp"
  android:padding="0dp"
  android:layout_margin="0dp">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:insetTop="0dp"
    android:insetBottom="0dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:insetTop="0dp"
    android:insetBottom="0dp"
    android:elevation="10dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: please attach your xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try to set up `translationZ` instead `elevation` (or next to it) - `translationZ` is intended to be "fixed" elevation and `elevation` is dynamic, can be animated. note that every `Button` has a `stateListAnimator` set up, which is overriding `elevation` parameter in default implementation. check out what it does in [HERE](https://proandroiddev.com/statelistanimator-a-powerful-little-tool-for-elevation-animation-4b31781e98a0)

easy way to fix would be to set for both `Button`s `android:stateListAnimator="@null"`, but you will loose some anims when click occur

easiest way would be to have one `FrameLayout`, inside two additional `FrameLayout`s and inside each one `Button` - fastest, but unelegant and not so efficient (but still for two buttons it won't be noticeable)